# How to solve the solution to this third order nonhomogeneous ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am supposed to solve this nonhomogeneous ordinary differential equation.

$$ x^3\frac{d^3y}{dx^3}-3x^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+6x\frac{dy}{dx}-6y=2x^4e^x $$

I attempted in solving this problem through finding the particular and the homogeneous solution.  In finding the particular solution, I have attempted in using the method of undetermined coefficients.  However, I was not sure of what function to use in finding the particular solution.

Comment: Try $e^x(ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e)$

Comment: Whoops, meant $2x e^x$.

Comment: Following Frederick's track, $y=2 e^x x + c_ 1 x + c_ 2 x^2 + c_ 3 x^3$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. Transformation $y(x)=z(\log x)$.
Then
$$
y'=\frac{z'(\log x)}{x},\quad y''=\frac{z''(\log x)-z'(\log x))}{x^2},\quad
y'''=\frac{z'''(\log x)-3z''(\log x)+2z'(\log x)}{x^3}.
$$
Then our equation becomes:
\begin{align}
x^3\frac{d^3y}{dx^3}-3x^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+6x\frac{dy}{dx}-6y &=
\left(z'''-3z''+2z'\right)-
3\left(z''-z'\right)+6z'-6z \\ &=
z'''-6z''+11z'-6z,
\end{align}
and it is finally transformed as
$$
z'''(\log x)-6z''(\log x)+11z'(\log x)-6z(\log x)=x^3\mathrm{e}^x,
$$
or
$$
z'''(x)-6z''(x)+11z'(x)-6z(x)=\mathrm{e}^{3x}\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{e}^x}.
$$
The general solution of the homogeous equation is
$$
z(x)=c_1\mathrm{e}^x+c_2\mathrm{e}^{2x}+c_3\mathrm{e}^{3x}.
$$

Then variation of parameters and inverse transformation.